# Delay for 1 second the disappearance of a dropdown menu when the mouse is moved away, unless it is returned

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, timeout, delay

Here is my HTML navbar

```
<nav>
    <ul id="mainnav">
        <li><a href="#">a thing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">some stuff</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="###">dropdown1</a></li>
                <li><a href="###">dropdown2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>           
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and the Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#mainnav ul').hide();

$('#mainnav li > a').hover(
      function () {
      //show its submenu
        $('ul', this.parentNode).stop().slideDown(0) = set 
      }
    );

$('#mainnav li').hover(null, 
      function () {
      //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this.parentNode).stop().delay(1000).slideUp(0); 
    });
```

I got the JavaScript from a jsfiddle and made it work out. I am quite competent in HTML and CSS, but apart from fairly obvious logic, I would say JavaScript is alien to me.

With the CSS it all looks like this: [image]

I'm looking for a CSS snippet that, when I take my mouse **OFF** (hover(null)) of the dropdown menu and it doesn't disappear *immediately*, but rather delays until after a second, **but won't disappear if i put my mouse back onto the menu before it does**.

I have had a really good look, but couldn't find any answer on the site that not only addresses this precise issue directly but is also simple enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g1f0nth5/) I should say javascript is not a good solution of that case .. css is a very better way to achieve that .. anyway

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainnav li ul').hide()
    $('#mainnav li').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).css('background','yellow');
        $(this).find('ul').slideDown(700);
    });
    $('#mainnav li').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).css('background','none');
        $(this).find('ul').slideUp(700);
    });
});
```

in css [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/odsb86o2/1/)

```
#mainnav li{
    background: #eee; 
}
#mainnav li ul li{
    background: none; 
}
#mainnav li:hover{
   background: yellow;
}
#mainnav li:hover ul{
    height: 100px;
    transition-delay: 0s;
     transition-duration: 1s;
}
#mainnav li ul{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    transition-delay: 10s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

transition-delay: 10s; the submenu will disapear after 10s so wait for it

Comment: i'm sorry, but this doesn't have the desired effect. sure it slows the slideUp, but i don't want the slideUp to start _at all_ until _a couple seconds after_ my mouse has left the dropdown menu.... hmm

Comment: This is a functional solution, but it requires that each and every mouseenter and mouseleave event be completed in full before the menu becomes useable. Swipe your mouse over #mainnav li a bunch of times, and watch.

Comment: i'm sorry this still isn't helping.


the purpose of this delay for me is this: that if the user move the mouse off momentarily, they can return it onto the dropdown menu without having to go back up and rehover on the main nav heading.


basically, if i take my mouse off and put it back onto the dropdown menu _before_ it disappears, it _still_ disappears! i want it to disappear, after a delay, **unless** i return the mouse to the dropdown menu. does this make sense? do you have any suggestions @sabaeus?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I think the above pure css solution is better.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/dqisv/g1f0nth5/3/

Set the default submenu display to none, then use jQuery's addClass to set the display of that element to block. Add a delay, then create a queue item to remove that class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#mainnav li').hover(
        function () {
             $('ul', this).addClass('subnav-show').delay(2000).queue(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('subnav-show').dequeue();
            });               
        });
});
```

You could alternately try to use this: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html